# PHP between HTML tag echo

Tags: php, html

I need to have PHP between my echo between a html tag, anyone can help ?

If you see my code, I want the `li` to have a PHP `if` in between it.
please help. thanks.

```
echo '<li id="dm-item1"' if($currentMenuId == '131') { 
echo 'class="current active"'; } '>';
```

I want to echo this :

```
<li id="dm-item1">
```

With this in between

```
<?php if($currentMenuId == '131') { echo 'class="current active"'; } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?> <li id="dm-item1" <?php if($currentMenuId == '131') echo 'class="current active"';?> >
```

Just close the PHP when you are bout to use HTML tags, don't print them. Print only the variable content.

Answer (score 6):

Simply this:-

```
<?php
$activeClass = ($currentMenuId == '131') ? ' class="current active" ' : '';
?>

<li id="dm-itm1" <?php echo $activeClass ?>>
```

Comment: great answer, thanks, but i the menu id changes, its a drawer menu.
so it wont help me, i will have to write that for every menu item.
thanks anyways, cheers

Answer (score 4):

```
echo '<li id="dm-item1"' . (($currentMenuId == '131') ? ' class="current active"' : '') . '>';
```

You where almost correct.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
echo '<li id="dm-item1"';
if($currentMenuId == '131') { 
   echo ' class="current active" '; 
} 
echo '>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator to check condition and concat the result to your echo statement, you can add classname or keep it empty if condition doesn't true.

```
echo '<li id="dm-item1"' . ($currentMenuId == '131') ? ' class="current active"' : '' . '>';
```